# SQL - assign variable with values from different columns based on value of column

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

I am new to SQL Server. My programming background is in SAS. I am currently using SQL Server Management Studio v18.5. I am trying to determine how to solve a couple of problems:

I want to assign new variables to existing columns, depending on the value of those columns. I have read about declaring variables using set and select, but I am having trouble translating that information to what I need to do. I have a view which contains several thousand records. I want the variable logic applied to each record in the view. The desired result is that I create a new view with just the new variable name and other associated data, excluding the original column names.

In SAS, my code would look like:

```
    If newctry<>' ' then countryname = newctry; 
                    else countryname = mailingcountry;
```

The existing columns are `newctry` and `mailingcountry`. The column `newctry` only has values when the `mailingcountry` value was invalid, otherwise the record value is blank.

I have different instances of this type of situation. Do I need to create subqueries for each of these instances? If someone could provide an example of how this might work in SQL, I would really appreciate it.  An example of the SQL code I have tried is:

```
DECLARE @countryname VARCHAR(50)

SELECT recordid, recorddate, newctry, mailingcountry
FROM viewname

SELECT @countryname = newctry FROM viewname WHERE newctry <> ' ']
SELECT @countryname = mailingcountry FROM viewname WHERE newctry = ' '
```

The other question I have is that I have received errors when I have included multiple `CASE` statements with different `END` names in the `Select` statement. Do I need subqueries for each `CASE` statement?

Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear to me exactly what you are trying to do.  I do not know SAS, but in T-SQL, normal variables are always scalars: they can only contain a single value, not a list nor a table.  There also table-variables which can contain a table of values, but you have to explicitly DECLARE them as table-variables.   Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want a `case` expression:

```
select (case when newctry <> ' ' then newctry else mailingcountry end) as countryname
```

Comment: There should be an END in there someplace.